# Cannot destructure property 'dispatch' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.useContext(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having troubles with my authentication. It works well until I add a Router, at which point it crashes. Why would it occur because of the router and work otherwise?

Anyways, here's where it crashes, at const {dispatch } in the Login component

```
import { AuthContext } from "./App";
export const Login = () => {
  const { dispatch } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const initialState = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    isSubmitting: false,
    errorMessage: null
  };
```

Calling it from the App component:

```
function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <main>

      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          state,
          dispatch
      }}
      >
      </AuthContext.Provider>
      <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/gallery" component={GetPhotos} />
            <Route exact path="/">
              {!state.isAuthenticated ? <Login /> : <GetPhotos state={state} AuthContext={AuthContext} />}
            </Route>
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    </main>
```

Appreciate any help and guidelines!

Comment: do you fix it ?